# Alt tag equivalent in an SVG <Image> element

Tags: html, image, svg, accessibility, alt

When I use the `<img>` HTML tag I always use an `alt` attribute for accessibility.

Adding the `alt="some text"` into the SVG `<image>` element doesn't seem to work?

What is the best way to provide alternative text in this example?

I have to use the SVG `<image>` element so I can't take alternative DOM element answers.

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 910 1295" style="enable-background:new 0 0 910 1295;" xml:space="preserve">
  <image width="910" height="1295" xlink:href="https://i.postimg.cc/43DKn46z/colours.jpg">
  </image>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent to the alt tag in SVG is the [`<desc>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements) child element.

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 910 1295" style="enable-background:new 0 0 910 1295;" xml:space="preserve">
  <image width="910" height="1295" xlink:href="https://i.postimg.cc/43DKn46z/colours.jpg">
    <desc>Some description of the image</desc>
  </image>
</svg>
```